# How can I change my wallpaper based on the wifi network or SSID?

Tags: windows-8.1, desktop-customization, ssid

I'm looking for a way to change my desktop wallpaper based on remembered Wifi Networks. (Windows 8.1)

Comment: This sounds like a great place to put a PowerShell script to use...

Comment: Thanks for the idea about PowerShell Ill see if can work that out!